# Constructing undirected edge list

Tags: python, graph, edge-list

I'm trying to construct a simple edge list for an undirected graph containing all possible edges. I used to do it using the cartesian product of the node list by itself & then filtering out duplicated & self edges. This time the size of the input is too large to afford to store unnecessary edges momentarily. Thus, I'm trying to use nested loops to get the needed edges directly from the first time.

Here is the code I wrote:

```py
node_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for i in node_list:
    for j in node_list:
        if i < j:
            source.append(i)
            target.append(j)
        
loop_data = pd.DataFrame({'source': source, 'target':target})
print(loop_data)
```

The output I get is pretty unexpected. Instead of saving the source & target nodes in their respective lists, the program is keeping both the source & the target nodes in both source & target columns. Here is the current state of the output.

```py
   source target
0       A      A
1       B      B
2       A      A
3       C      C
4       A      A
5       D      D
6       B      B
7       C      C
8       B      B
9       D      D
10      C      C
11      D      D
```

This is the expected form of output (ignore row indexing) :

```py
   source target
1       A      B
2       A      C
3       A      D
6       B      C
7       B      D
11      C      D
```

I can't find where the problem exists. The issue seems to be with appending to both of the source & target lists.

Comment: You didn't show how you create `source` or `target`. We can guess, and there are some guesses that would explain this behavior, but if you make people guess, that makes it harder to help you.

Comment: Please provide a working, reproducible example. After attempting to fill missing pieces of the code myself it works as expected.

Comment: If I start source and target as empty lists your code works for me

Comment: Wild guess: `source = target = []` somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you initialise each variable as the empty list (`[]`) the code works as expected. So I suggest you review how you are initialising the `source` and `target` variables:

```
source = []  # empty list
target = []  # different empty list
node_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in node_list:
    for j in node_list:
        if i < j:
            source.append(i)
            target.append(j)

loop_data = pd.DataFrame({'source': source, 'target': target})
print(loop_data)
```

**Output**

```
  source target
0      A      B
1      A      C
2      A      D
3      B      C
4      B      D
5      C      D
```

Since you want to construct an [**undirected graph**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Graph), I suggest you use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the *edges*:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

node_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

res = pd.DataFrame(data=combinations(node_list, r=2), columns=["source", "target"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  source target
0      A      B
1      A      C
2      A      D
3      B      C
4      B      D
5      C      D
```

The reason for using `combinations` is that it avoids the Python level `for`-loop therefore for larger lists it should be faster. It is also in my opinion more *pythonic*.

**Timings**

For a `node_list` of 676 elements, I get the following timings:

```
%timeit c = combinations_approach(node_list)
19.7 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit o = original_approach(node_list)
41.2 ms ± 64.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

where the functions `combinations_approach` and `original_approach` are:

```
def original_approach(node_list):
    source = []
    target = []

    for i in node_list:
        for j in node_list:
            if i < j:
                source.append(i)
                target.append(j)

    return pd.DataFrame({'source': source, 'target': target})


def combinations_approach(node_list):
    return pd.DataFrame(combinations(sorted(node_list), r=2), columns=["source", "target"])
```

Comment: OP code works as expected if variables are defined correctly.